# success url of magento after paypal website payment pro hosted

Tags: php, magento, paypal

For success page of default methods in magento is `/checkout/oneage/success`

For success page of paypal website standard is `/paypal/standard/success/`

*Could anyone please tell me what will be the success url of paypal website hosted pro?* After some digging I found it to be `paypal/hostedpro/success/`

Is it correct? I need the success url to set as return url in website payment hosted pro in paypal side.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

in **Mage/Paypal/controllers/StandardController** there is such method as **successAction**, which finaly redirects you to checkout/success/onepage

```
/**
 * when paypal returns
 * The order information at this point is in POST
 * variables.  However, you don't want to "process" the order until you
 * get validation from the IPN.
 */
public function  successAction()
{
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
    $session->setQuoteId($session->getPaypalStandardQuoteId(true));
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->setIsActive(false)->save();
    $this->_redirect('checkout/onepage/success', array('_secure'=>true));
}
```

In **HostedproController** there no **successAction**, there is only **returnAction**

```
/**
 * When a customer return to website from gateway.
 */
public function returnAction()
{
    $session = $this->_getCheckout();
    //TODO: some actions with order
    if ($session->getLastRealOrderId()) {
        $this->_redirect('checkout/onepage/success');
    }
}
```

Comment: i need to set magento success url in website payment hosted pro of paypal. what will the url for it? The payment status i am getting as pending payment after successful completion of purchase.

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure, maybe try this 'checkout/onepage/success'